# Remove fill around legend key in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to remove the gray rectangle around the legend. I have tried various methods but none have worked.

```
ggtheme <- 
theme(
axis.text.x = element_text(colour='black'),
axis.text.y = element_text(colour='black'),
panel.background = element_blank(),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_rect(colour='black', fill=NA),
strip.background = element_blank(),
legend.justification = c(0, 1),
legend.position = c(0, 1),
legend.background = element_rect(colour = NA),
legend.key = element_rect(colour = "white", fill = NA),
legend.title = element_blank()
)

colors <- c("red", "blue")
df <- data.frame(year = c(1:10), value = c(10:19), gender = rep(c("male","female"),each=5))
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value)) + geom_point(aes(colour=gender))  +
stat_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, level=0, size = 1, 
    aes(group = gender, colour=gender)) +
ggtheme + scale_color_manual(values = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Not able to add an image because I lack the points

Comment: added the screenshot for you.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You get this grey color inside legend keys because you use `stat_smooth()` that as default makes also confidence interval around the line with some fill (grey if `fill=` isn't used inside the `aes()`).

One solution is to set `se=FALSE` for `stat_smooth()` if you don't need the confidence intervals.

```
  +stat_smooth(method = "loess", formula = y ~ x, level=0, size = 1, 
              aes(group = gender, colour=gender),se=FALSE)
```

Another solution is to use the function `guides()` and `override.aes=` to remove fill from the legend but keep confidence intervals around lines.

```
  + guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))
```

Comment: thank you, this override can it be placed in the theme?

Comment: No because it is not theme() element but determines how legend is made based on aesthetics.

Comment: For whatever reason se=F didn't work for me -- i went with + theme(legend.key=element.blank())

Comment: @badgley means element_blank() but his comment worked for me

Comment: For myself, I had to use `legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)` for the desired effect.

Comment: @Justapigeon yes worked for me too where other solutions did not. Should probably be the accepted answer but I'm too lazy to do anything about it

Answer (score 51):

```
theme_set(theme_gray() + theme(legend.key=element_blank()))
```

If you want also to remove grey background:

```
theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(legend.key=element_blank()))
```

Comment: This is the general approach, but it was essentially tested by the OP. As Didzis's answer suggests, the matter is more complicated here because of the default themes of ``stat_smooth()``

Answer (score 24):

```
+ theme(legend.background=element_blank())
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Maybe explain a bit more if you think this really does work, else better remove it.

Comment: This command remove the background of the legend. It is normally used with the legend.key command. For example:  theme(legend.key=element_blank(),legend.background=element_blank())

Comment: This is the answer green check