# ggplot2: cannot override 2nd legend aesthetics when using stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

Pumpkin Helmet (3.1.2), ggplot2_1.0.0.

```
library(ggplot2)
some_diamonds <- subset(diamonds, color %in% c('D', 'E', 'F'))
g <- ggplot(some_diamonds, aes(carat, depth, linetype=cut, colour=color)) +
    stat_smooth(se=F) + scale_colour_grey()
```

The desired color aesthetic shows up correctly in the legend for `color` (and, crucially, in the plot itself), but the colour for `cut` defaults to `stat_smooth`'s default (blue). The [usual tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066077/remove-fill-around-legend-key-in-ggplot) do not seem to work in this case, e.g.:

```
g <- ggplot(some_diamonds, aes(carat, depth, linetype=cut, colour=color)) + 
   stat_smooth(se=F) 
g + scale_colour_grey() + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = 
   list(colour='black')
```

In fact, I'm not even sure how to access any elements of the second legend. This

```
g + scale_colour_grey(guide=guide_legend(title="Title", order=2))
```

just changes the title of the first legend to "Title"; similarly,

```
g + scale_colour_grey() + 
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour='black'), order=2))
```

overrides `cut` but not `color`, no matter the value for `order` (or even if omitted).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've come awfully close already! What helps here is simply to change the name of the argument in `guides()` to the name of the feature that you're trying to change, which is the `linetype`.

```
g + guides(linetype = guide_legend(title = "Variable: cut",  # changes the second legend
                                   override.aes = list(colour = "black")), 
           color = guide_legend(title = "Variable: color"))  # changes the first legend
```

[image: plot with changed legend's color]

Comment: d'oh! that does it all right. although I find the logic a little opaque. and in any event this only seems to affect the first legend: compare with `g + scale_colour_grey()+ guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype='dashed')))`

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean here (I'm not a native speaker) but I guess you're right: Each feature with a legend has its own argument in `guides()`. And yes, the expression seems a little long for the little amount of change that comes with it.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering what the more general strategy for accessing elements of the 2nd, 3rd... legends are. How would you change the title of `cut`, for example? Perhaps this warrants a separate question?

Comment: In this particular case wouldn't it work the same way? `cut` is the name of the variable, but the feature in question is `linetype` - `g + guides(linetype = guide_legend(title ="new title", override.aes = list(colour='black')))`. Or have I misunderstood? The packages `grid`, `gridExtra` and others can help to change `ggplot2` plots on the core level (but I'm not sure if you need this here).

Comment: Feel free to accept my post of you think that it answers your question.