# Changing the legend colours in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some problems altering the appearance of a legend in ggplot2. It is probably a generic problem but just in case, here is my example data and the lmer model that I am plotting so it can be reproduced.

```
tempEf <- data.frame(
  N = rep(c("1", "2","1", "2","1", "2","1"), each=5, times=11),
  Myc = rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), each=1, times=77),
  TRTYEAR = runif(385, 1, 15),
  site = rep(c(1:77), each=5, times=1),#77 sites
  Asp = runif(385, 1, 5))

# Make up some response data
tempEf$r <- 2*tempEf$TRTYEAR +                   
  -8*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="1") +
  4*as.numeric(tempEf$N=="1") +
  0.1*tempEf$TRTYEAR * as.numeric(tempEf$N=="1") +
  0.2*tempEf$TRTYEAR*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="1") +
  -11*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="1")*as.numeric(tempEf$N=="1")+ 
  0.5*tempEf$TRTYEAR*as.numeric(tempEf$Myc=="1")*as.numeric(tempEf$N=="1")+ 
  as.numeric(tempEf$site) +  #Random intercepts; intercepts will increase by 1
  tempEf$TRTYEAR/10*rnorm(385, mean=0, sd=2)    #Add some noise
#fit model
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(r ~ Myc * N + TRTYEAR + Asp + (1|site), data=tempEf)
tempEf$fit <- predict(model)   #Add model fits to dataframe
```

With thanks to some help from this website, I have now obtained the plot I want with this:

```
pred <- ggpredict(model, c("TRTYEAR", "Myc"))

myplot<-plot(pred, rawdata  = TRUE, use.theme = TRUE)
```

and tweaking things a little, using a colour scale from ggsci:

```
myplot<-myplot+
  scale_color_npg(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")) + scale_fill_npg() + 
  labs(x="\nTreatment Year",y="Ratings\n")
```

My problem is that I can’t seem to make the legend so that it just shows the actual colour of the ribbons/lines – currently each 'block' in the legend is grey, with just a line of the colour across it. I’d like them to be a solid block of the correct colour, or at least just get rid of the grey and have white with a line of the correct colour.
I have tried using this:

```
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill =  'pink'))
```

which works to colour in the legend blocks a different colour to grey, but only works with a single colour for all 5, and doesn’t work if I put “white” or “transparent”.

is there a simple solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066077/remove-fill-around-legend-key-in-ggplot). You have to use `guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))`.As for the lines color I think it's ok

Comment: that works, thank you! Any way to get the blocks shaded with the right colours? or do they have to stay white?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a way to get the colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not particularly neat and I'm sure there are better ways, but if you play around with "size" you can colour the blocks:

```
myplot + 
 guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=pred$Myc, size=5)))
```

I hope that helps!