# Remove fill around legend key for geom_ribbon in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to remove the fill inside the legend that is created with geom_ribbon. Note that [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066077/remove-fill-around-legend-key-in-ggplot) do not solve this particular issue.

**Minimal Working Example**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp*disp, data= mtcars)

me <- ggeffect(fit,
               ci.lvl = .95,
               type = "fe",
               terms = c("hp", "disp"))

ggplot(data = me,
       mapping = aes(x = x, y = predicted, linetype = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low,
                  ymax = conf.high),
              alpha = .5)
```

[image]

I want this plot, but I want the legend to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question! A potential solution is to include `show.legend = FALSE` and also remove the legend key background using `theme()` (each of these actions won't 'work' on their own), e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# install.packages("ggeffects")
library(ggeffects)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp*disp, data= mtcars)

me <- ggeffect(fit,
               ci.lvl = .95,
               type = "fe",
               terms = c("hp", "disp"))

ggplot(data = me,
       mapping = aes(x = x, y = predicted, linetype = group)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low,
                  ymax = conf.high),
              alpha = .5, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly with my actual data - thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome - thanks for including all the necessary details in your question :)